# Composable using scalaz Arrow?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have two functions.

```
  def process(date: DateTime, invoice: Invoice, user: User, reference: Reference) : (Action, Iterable[Billable])

  def applyDiscount(billable: Billable) : Billable
```

How can I compose these so that I have a single function of (DateTime, Invoice, User, Reference) => (Action, Iterable[Billable])

Here is the poor mans way of what I want

```
  def buildFromInvoice(user: User, order: Invoice, placementDate: DateTime, reference: Reference) = {
    val ab = billableBuilder.fromInvoice(user, order, placementDate, reference)
    (ab._1, ab._2.map(applyDiscount(_))
  }
```

Comment: you want a function that first executes `process` and then `applyDiscount` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Are these two functions composable using Scalaz arrow and if so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have (simplifying) is:

```
val f: A => (B, M[C]) //M is a Functor
val g: C => C
```

I can think of a few ways of doing this. I think my preference is:

```
(a: A) => g.lift[M].second apply f(a)
```

Or also:

```
(a: A) => f(a) :-> g.lift[M]
```

However, there is possibly a *pointfree* way - although not necessarily so, of course

- `lift` is a method on `Function1W` which lifts the function into the realm of the functor M
- `second` is a method on `MAB` which applies the function down the right-hand-side of a `Bifunctor`
- `:->` is a method available to `Bifunctors` denoting the application of a function on the rhs.

**EDIT** - *missingfaktor* appears to be correct in saying `f andThen g.lift[M].second` works:

```
scala> import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> case class A(); case class B(); case class C()
defined class A
defined class B
defined class C

scala> lazy val f: A => (B, List[C]) = sys.error("")
f: A => (B, List[C]) = <lazy>

scala> lazy val g: C => C = sys.error("")
g: C => C = <lazy>
```

Pointfree:

```
scala> lazy val h = f andThen g.lift[List].second
h: A => (B, List[C]) = <lazy>
```

Comment: Perhaps `f andThen g.lift[M].second`.

Comment: Nicely distilled, amazing how much clearer things are when you can *only* see the types!

Comment: Awesome answer.  I totally understand each step here after playing around in the repl.  Applying this to my problem I came up with these two solutions: val bfc = billableBuilder.fromContract(_: User, _: Contract, _: DateTime, _: Option[Order]) :-> (applyDiscount(_)).lift[Iterable]  and val bfc = (applyDiscount(_)).lift[Iterable].second apply billableBuilder.fromContract(_: User, _: Contract, _: DateTime, _: Option[Order])

Comment: Also note that I could not get the 'andThen' working for my situation.  andThen seems to be only defined on Function1 where as apply is defined on all FunctionXX traits.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes Do you have any insight on why `:->` implicitly works on the second argument (and there is no symmetric way to apply this on the first argument). Or would this be worth another question.

Comment: @Debilski - you can use `<-:` for the first element of the tuple. Or is this not the question?

Comment: @oxbow_lakes Yes but with `<-:` I’d have to invert the order of f and g. Which makes this operator even more confusing. I suppose there must be a reason or convention for that.

Comment: it's so you can do `l <-: pair :-> r` for functions l and r

Comment: Why `lazy val` instead of `def`? And, on trunk, `???` instead of `sys.error("")`... :-)